# Apk installed using adb , will receive updates from playstore?

Tags: android, google-play

I created an apk and installed the local copy on my mobile using adb, later I kept the same apk in the market.

Now,

1. Could I install both the app´s in the device?
2. When installing the market app, will it show me replace your old application?
3. After a month, I place an update to market - still I have the same local apk in my device - do I get the update from market?

Sreeram

Comment: 1. you can not two app with same package, if you want to do it you have to keep package name different, and your local apk is different from your market one

Comment: 3. no you did not get market update,because you google market cant keep track of that app,its locally installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I install both the apps in the device?

No. If you have the same package name, it will try to replace the already existing app, provided both the apps are signed with the same Keys.

> When installing the market app, will it show me replace your old
>   application?

No, if you have used the same key to sign your app. If you have used different keys to sign your application(local and Google Play), you will not be able to overwrite the existing app. It will throw a "SIGNATURE MISMATCH" error while you try to install.

> After a month, I place an update to market - still I have the same
>   local apk in my device - do I get the update from market?

You wouldn't be able to receive automatic update, but if you have signed the apps with the same key, the Google Play app will recognize that you already have a version of that app and you can update it manually.

Answer (score 6):

A few days ago I had to test the play store update mechanics for my company. My summarized results lead to following conditions for an play store update:

- The package name of both apps has to be the same.
- To be able to update an apk (doesn't matter the update source) both apk's signatures need to match.
- The `android:versionCode` of the market apk needs to be higher than the one of the apk installed on the device.

Let me quickly explain the results. First of all, the package name is the value which is used by the android OS to determine if an apk is the same or not. The apk's signing key proofs that the developer (or signer) is the same. And the `android:versionCode` is the simple value to check against if you want to know which version an apk has.

And finally, to answer your questions:

> 1) Only with different package names.
>
> 2) Only with the same package name and signature. The store will offer to update the apk if the stores `android:versionCode` is higher then the one installed.

And now the interesting part:

> 3) Yes you do get an update! It's the same behavior described before.

---

**Edit:**
Here the chart with my raw result data:

```
|Old source|Old version|New source|New version|Reinstall result|Store update available?|
|----------|-----------|----------|-----------|----------------|-----------------------|
|Store     |10         |Device    |5          |fail            |---                    |
|Store     |10         |Device    |10         |success         |no                     |
|Store     |10         |Device    |15         |success         |no                     |
|Device    |5          |Store     |10         |success         |yes                    |
|Device    |10         |Store     |10         |not possible    |no                     |
|Device    |15         |Store     |10         |not possible    |no                     |
```

Comment: good answer and the test results are pretty clear. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You should re-install from Market and then you will get updates, if you try to "update" from market, your device will uninstall yours and will install from 0 the app downloaded.

You can read a spanish blog... Maybe you can translate it. [Auto-Update-OutMarket APP](http://androcode.es/2012/03/aplicacion-auto-actualizable-sin-market/)